# Unable to show Snackbar from PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment, android-snackbar

I want to use Snackbar onSharedPreferenceChange() inside my PreferenceFragment hosted by a Activity.

**preference.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="ll_main">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/push_notification">
    <SwitchPreference android:title="@string/transectional_notification"
        android:key="trans_not"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:summary="@string/get_notified_about_any_changes_related_to_your_transections"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="@string/promotional_notification"
        android:key="prom_not"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:summary="@string/get_notified_about_referalls"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/other_notifications">
        <SwitchPreference android:title="@string/email_notifications"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="email_not" />
        <SwitchPreference android:title="@string/sms_notifications"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="sms_not"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/recommendation_setting">
    <com.til.recharger.widgets.PhoneEditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/mobile_no"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:summary="8587035342"
        android:key="mob_no_edit"/>
    <ListPreference android:title="@string/operator"
        android:summary="Airtel"
        android:key="operator_list"/>
    <ListPreference android:title="@string/circle"
        android:summary="New Delhi"
        android:key="circle_list"/>
    <ListPreference
        android:title="Plan type"
        android:entries="@array/listentries"
        android:entryValues="@array/listentries"
        android:summary="Postpaid"
        android:defaultValue="Prepaid"
        android:key="plan_key"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/plan_info">
    <com.til.recharger.widgets.NumberPickerPreference
        android:title="@string/bill_cycle"
        android:summary="2"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:key="bill_cycle_edit"/>
    <com.til.recharger.widgets.CustomEditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/monthly_data_limit"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:key="monthly_limit_edit"/>
    <ListPreference
        android:title="@string/preffered_network_type"
        android:entries="@array/mobiledataoptions"
        android:entryValues="@array/mobiledatavalues"
        android:summary="3G"
        android:defaultValue="3G"
        android:key="pref_data_list"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My function for showing snackbar is :

```
    public void hideKeyWithError(final String error) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AppUtils.hide_keyboard(getActivity());
            Snackbar.make(view,error,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, (300));
}
```

I don't know what to pass as 'view' to snackbar to show it.

PS : I tried passing PreferenceScreen to Snackbar, But didn't work out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this for get view

```
View view = getView();
```

So the code is.

```
public void hideKeyWithError(final String error) {
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        View view = getView();
        AppUtils.hide_keyboard(getActivity());
        Snackbar.make(view,error,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}, (300));
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. You saved my day.

Comment: Use `requireView()` in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

`View` param of `Snackbar.make()` means a view on which `Snackbar` can find parent to display `Snackbar` on the top of screen

> Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Try to pass your fragment component as a view